How to fetch all swaps of a token through RPC?
I want to fetch all swaps of a given token,
problems is getSignatureForAddress doesn't gives back all the transaction because in some of them the token address isn't included in the staticAccountKeys.
What I'm trying right now is rawdog by iterating though all blocks and parse the transactions, but it is wayyyyyy to slowww.
Any recommended way?

That's kind of the way, unfortunately, you could also use getSignaturesForAddress for the trading programs that you care about and parse those, but that'll still require fetching a lot of transactions
